# Individual Record Subform

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, record

I am fairly new to access and I am wondering about a form.

In my form, I want to have certain field values displayed based upon which row the user selects.

So, pretend a user selects Row B, I want a subform that displays data from only Row B.

Is this possible, and if so how? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I can do up a quick mockup of what im looking to do in paint really quickly if it will help to get my question across better.

Comment: I'm reading through, But I don't see much reference to my problem at hand.

Comment: That is correct, perhaps I am not understanding the termonology she uses to get this solution across, Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a subform for this.

Your main form is a continuous form and your data rows are displayed in the form's detail area, right?
If yes, you can just put bound textboxes in the form header or footer, and they will display the value of the selected row.

Here are some example screenshots I just made.
It's Access 2000 and it's in German (that's the only Access version that I have here), but you'll get the idea.

Design mode:
[image: Design mode]
*("Formularkopf" means "form header", and "Detailbereich" is "Detail" in English Access versions.)*

At runtime:
[image: At runtime]
Note that the textbox in the form header, which is bound to Field2, automatically displays the value of Field2 in the currently selected row.

Comment: A bound text box is just the dragged field off my Field List?

Comment: Yes, exactly! (you could also create a "normal" textbox and bind it by hand, but dragging it off the field list is easier)